# How do I link libcurl to my c++ program in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, libcurl

I need to use libcurl in a piece of software I am writing on my ubuntu machine. I am using Eclipse to write and compile all of the software. When I put the libcurl files in the same folder as the .cpp file, and include the curl.h file in the header, When I attempt to compile the program, It comes up with these errors:

```
Building target: sms
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o"sms"  ./src/sms.o   
./src/sms.o: In function `main':
/home/geekman/workspace/sms/Debug/../src/sms.cpp:38: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/home/geekman/workspace/sms/Debug/../src/sms.cpp:42: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/geekman/workspace/sms/Debug/../src/sms.cpp:44: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/geekman/workspace/sms/Debug/../src/sms.cpp:46: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/home/geekman/workspace/sms/Debug/../src/sms.cpp:47: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sms] Error 1
```

I took the contents of the include folder from libcurl, and placed them in the same folder as the .cpp file. then in the header of the .cpp file, I typed:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

I also tried:

```
#include "curl/curl.h"
```

Any ideas on the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your header file inclusions are just fine; your problem is occurring at the linking step.  In order to link against libcurl, you need to add the `-lcurl` command line option, assuming it's installed in a standard directory:

```
g++ -o sms ./src/sms.o -lcurl
```

If it's not installed in a standard directory, you also need to add the `-L/path/to/libcurl`, e.g. something like:

```
# Assuming that /home/geekman/workspace/libcurl is where libcurl.a is located
g++ -o sms ./src/sms.o -L/home/geekman/workspace/libcurl -lcurl
```

Also note that the `-lcurl` option has to appear *after* the list of object files you're linking, otherwise it won't link properly.

Comment: Some libcurl functions have additional dependencies, e.g. zlib, which may result some compiler warnings, e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606124/undefined-reference-to-inflate  Possible dependencies listed at  http://curl.haxx.se/docs/libs.html

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that -lcurl must be after the object files... You saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 10):

You can try to use `curl-config --libs`.

Comment: And for `curl-config` to be installed, you may want to install the `curl` development package (`curl-dev` or `curl-devel` or something like that).

Answer (score 5):

An alternate answer (the first one is excellent). Consider using the output returned by "pkg-config --libs libcurl" as an argument to your compiler.

For example,

> CPPFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs libcurl`
>
> g++ $CPPFLAGS myfile.o

Pkg-config is a standard way for open source libraries to communicate to you how to link against them / #include their files.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone who is using ecplise CDT then you need to do following. First on terminal enter

```
curl-config --libs
```

On my machine, the result is

```
-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lcurl
```

then do according to this screenshot and you will be able to compile. btw don't forget to add header files in your code

[image]

So you enter library folder path without -L and library name without -l because they will be automatically added by linker.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link the library to your program. With gcc (and most other compilers) you can specify the libraries to link with `-lname_wo_lib`, e.g. `-lcurl`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer, I had to link the curlpp library too. So to compile the main.cpp file which included the curlpp I had to do:

```
g++ main.cpp -lcurl -lcurlpp
```

Using only one of the two links would return different errors regarding different links. It is important to remind that this only worked because I had installed all the necessary libraries in the standard include folders

Comment: The references missing in the question are related to just libcurl-easy.

Answer (score 0):

Also see [GNU GCC Manual - Options for Linking](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) for a detailed explanation of the options Adam Rosenfield said. For standard search directories, see [An Introduction to GCC - for the GNU Compilers gcc and g++ - Setting Search Paths](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_21.html).