# mysql-udf-http http_get function Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, http-get, mysql-error-2013

I want to insert into MYSQL UDF function "http_get".

Currently I have a "mysql-udf-http.so" file that I import the function in the program, but to run it I get the error message:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server During query
```

In this link: "http://code.google.com/p/mysql-udf-http/issues/detail?id=3" appears just a post with a fix for this problem.
Now I'm trying to create from this new file "mysql-udf-http.c" a new file "mysql-udf-http.so"

My header data are:

```
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include </usr/include/mysql/mysql.h>
# include </home/admin/mysql-udf-http-1.0/curl-7.21.1/include/curl/curl.h>
# include "mysql-udf-http.h"
```

I make a compilation with the command "g++ -fPIC -I /usr/include/mysql/ -o mysql-udf-http.so -shared mysql-udf-http.c"
Showing no error message when compiling, but when I import the function in MYSQL, returns error message:

```
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can not open shared library 'mysql-udf-http.so' (errno: 22 / usr / lib64 / mysql / plugin / mysql-udf-http.so: undefined symbol: curl_easy_setopt)
```

In this other link: "[How do I link libcurl to my c++ program in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302282/how-do-i-link-libcurl-to-my-c-program-in-linux)" appears a review of how to do the compilation properly. I have no "libcurl.a" file, only one directory with libcurl other content file.

I enter the command to compile: `g++ -fPIC -I /usr/include/mysql/ -o mysql-udf-http.so -shared mysql-udf-http.c -L/home/admin/mysql-udf-http-1.0/curl-7.21.1/docs/libcurl/ -lcurl`
No compilation error messages.

But finally when importing into MYSQL error message:

```
ERROR 1127 (HY000): Can not find symbol 'http_get' in library'
```

Someone can correct mistakes or help me to do the "mysql-udf-http.so" valid for centOS 64bit?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this problem?