# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced when compile HTTPD

Tags: c++, apache, visual-studio-2015, linker

I'm compiling HTTPD 2.4.48 along with Lua, Zlib, cURL, jansson and OpenSSL.

Here is the list of files and software I use:

1. httpd-2.4.48
2. apr-1.7.0
3. apr-util-1.6.1
4. cURL 7.77.0
5. expat-2.4.1
6. jansson 2.13.1
7. Lua 5.4.3
8. mod_fcgid 2.3.9
9. openssl-1.1.1k
10. pcre-8.44
11. ZLIB 1.2.11
12. ActivePerl v5.28.1.2801 (x64)
13. CMake v3.20.3 (x64)
14. NASM v2.15.05 (x64)
15. Gawk v3.1.6-1 (x86)

The whole compile statement I use:

Visual Studio 2015: call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

```
*****************
** ZLIB Build **
*****************

cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\zlib\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
nmake
nmake install

****************
** Pcre Build **
****************
cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\pcre\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DPCRE_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DPCRE_BUILD_PCRECPP=OFF -DPCRE_BUILD_PCREGREP=OFF -DPCRE_SUPPORT_PCREGREP_JIT=OFF -DPCRE_SUPPORT_UTF=ON -DPCRE_SUPPORT_UNICODE_PROPERTIES=ON -DPCRE_NEWLINE=CRLF -DINSTALL_MSVC_PDB=OFF ..
nmake
nmake install

*****************
** Expat Build **
*****************
cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\expat\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
nmake
nmake install

*******************
** OpenSSL Build **
*******************
cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\openssl
perl Configure VC-WIN64A --release --prefix=\phpStudy\Apache --openssldir=\phpStudy\Apache\conf enable-camellia no-idea no-mdc2 no-ssl2 no-ssl3
nmake
nmake install

***************
** Lua Build **
***************

cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\lua\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
nmake
nmake install

****************
** cURL Build **
****************

cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\curl\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
nmake
nmake install

*******************
** jansson Build **
*******************

cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\jansson\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
nmake
nmake install

***************
** APR Build **
***************
cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\apr\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DMIN_WINDOWS_VER=0x0600 -DAPR_HAVE_IPV6=ON -DAPR_INSTALL_PRIVATE_H=ON -DAPR_BUILD_TESTAPR=OFF -DINSTALL_PDB=OFF ..
nmake
nmake install

********************
** APR-Util Build **
********************
cd /D C:\httpd\srclib\apr-util\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=\phpStudy\Apache  -DAPU_HAVE_CRYPTO=ON -DAPR_BUILD_TESTAPR=OFF -DINSTALL_PDB=OFF ..
nmake
nmake install

******************
** Apache Build **
******************
cd /D C:\httpd\bin
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\phpStudy\Apache -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DENABLE_MODULES=i -DINSTALL_PDB=OFF ..
nmake
nmake install
```

Everything worked almost perfectly, however in the last step when I compile HTTPD I got the error:

```
[ 44%] Linking C shared library mod_md.so
LINK: command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\mod_md.dir\objects1.rsp /out:mod_md.so /implib:mod_md.lib /pdb:C:\httpd\bin\mod_md.pdb /dll /version:0.0 /base:@C:/httpd/bin/BaseAddr.ref,mod_md.so /machine:x64 /INCREMENTAL:NO \phpStudy\Apache\lib\libssl.lib \phpStudy\Apache\lib\libcrypto.lib \phpStudy\Apache\lib\jansson.lib mod_watchdog.lib libhttpd.lib \phpStudy\Apache\lib\libapr-1.lib \phpStudy\Apache\lib\libaprutil-1.lib \phpStudy\Apache\lib\apr_ldap-1.lib ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib \phpStudy\Apache\lib\pcre.lib ws2_32.lib mswsock.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:mod_md.so.manifest" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
   Creating library mod_md.lib and object mod_md.exp
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_global_init referenced in function md_curl_init
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_slist_append referenced in function curlify_headers
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_slist_free_all referenced in function md_curl_req_cleanup
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_easy_strerror referenced in function md_curl_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_easy_init referenced in function internals_setup
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_easy_setopt referenced in function internals_setup
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_easy_perform referenced in function md_curl_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function md_curl_req_cleanup
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_easy_getinfo referenced in function md_curl_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_multi_init referenced in function md_curl_multi_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_multi_add_handlereferenced in function md_curl_multi_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_multi_remove_handle referenced in function md_curl_multi_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_multi_wait referenced in function md_curl_multi_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_multi_perform referenced in function md_curl_multi_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_multi_cleanup referenced in function md_curl_multi_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_multi_info_read referenced in function md_curl_multi_perform
md_curl.c.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_multi_strerror referenced in function md_curl_multi_perform
mod_md.so : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I found out the answer of this question: [Visual Studio 2015 curl will not statically link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762859/visual-studio-2015-curl-will-not-statically-link/47251782)

Change the code of the `md_curl.c` file to:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wldap32.lib" )
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib" )
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

But this error still occurs.

Where did I go wrong? I'm getting confused because this is the first time I've encountered this error when compiling HTTPD.

Your answer will be very helpful. I would appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you fix issues, start by the first one (cause solving that may remove the remaining), which in you case seems to be:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_global_init referenced in function md_curl_init
```

And it basically is telling us that, the `md_curl_init` method calls `curl_global_init` method, but while compile-time **declaration** was available, the linker-time required **definition** is missing.

Anyway, to fix this ensure `curl` is added as a library, I mean, is currently not in your linker command-line (not in what you posted at least).

---

**Edit** I will suggest you approaches, for how you can do that.

But first, giving it more time, I see that:

1. Yes, you already compile `curl`.
2. Your "whole compile statement" thing is using `C:\httpd\srclib\curl\bin` as build-directory for `cURL`.
3. Also, you should be able to find `curl.lib` in   `C:\httpd\srclib\curl\bin` directory (which was used as build-directory).

#### Approach #1:

Create a root `CMakeFiles.txt` file and add your other projects with `add_subdirectory(...)` method.

I **recommend** this approach, as `CMake` will handle for you the task of finding `curl` **automatically**.

I mean, you just would need to do something like:

```
target_link_libraries(myTargetThatNeedsCurl
    curl
)
```

#### Approach #2:

If you don't want to change "whole compile statement" thing, then your only choice may be to place `curl.lib` somewhere that your other build-script can find it (manually or through some custom `install(...)` method calls, I leave that to you).

#### Approach #3:

1. First, edit `httpd` project (the `C:\httpd\CMakeFiles.txt` file), and add `add_subdirectory(srclib/curl)` somewhere in beginning.
2. Then, find `cURL` target's name, like, open the `C:\httpd\srclib\curl\CMakeFiles.txt` file and see all `add_library(...)` call's first argument (one of them is what we want).
3. Finally, edit `httpd` project again, but now add what you found in step-2 as argument to `target_link_libraries(...)` method.

> **Note** that Approach #3 is same as #2, but just for cURL (instead of adding all sub-directories).

Comment: I updated adding `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` to the compile command line. I didn't specify a drive letter so it could work on many different drives later on.
I looked in the folder `\phpStudy\Apache` but didn't find the `curl.lib` file you said but the above error still occurs. However, in the `\phpStudy\Apache\bin` folder I do see `curl.exe` and `curl.dll` files!

Comment: @TầnQuảng I hope you saw my edit (and that you could fix it by now).

Comment: I tried compiling directly at the root directory instead of the `bin` directory. I noticed the Curl include directory in the Apache httpd configuration summary was empty even though the above detected the CURL (and of course the error still occurred): https://i.imgur.com/llymFrx.png

I noticed this time, in the folder `\phpStudy\apache\lib` appeared a file `libcurl_imp.lib` which I previously compiled but did not have.
I still don't understand the `Approach #1` you give, I compile everything with CMake so all the features that I compile have a `CMakeFiles.txt` file.

Comment: I added another approach, but I think, I can not fix curl include dir without source access (maybe clear your entire build-cache).

Comment: I tried recompiling, adding `-DCURL_INCLUDE_DIR=/httpd/srclib/curl/bin` directly to the command line. But that error still occurs. I reviewed the previous version's `CMakeLists.txt` file, the fix in the previous version was to change: `SET(mod_md_requires OPENSSL_FOUND CURL_FOUND JANSSON_FOUND)` to `SET(mod_md_requires CURL_FOUND)` is compilable without happening gives error but it doesn't work in this version. Now, I will try your way!

Comment: I looked at the file `CMakeFiles.txt` in `\httpd\srclib\curl` but there is no `add_library` in it!

Comment: That method is required to register a library (no matter if static or shared), I mean, it is used for sure, but maybe search in all files in that directory (using some tool, like `WinRAR`).

Comment: I looked for `add_library` in the entire `srclib/curl` directory, there were 3 results in 2 `CMakeLists.txt` files: `\httpd\srclib\curl\lib\CMakeLists.txt` and `\httpd\srclib\curl\tests\libtest\CMakeLists.txt`. Here is the code of those files (I have the corresponding path annotation in the description): https://imgur.com/a/xH6hzhL
What should I do next?

Comment: They made it too complicated, anyway, now search where `LIB_NAME` variable is set, then you can finally handle step-3 (except if you can not find `target_link_libraries` as well).

Comment: I see at the top of the file it says: `set(LIB_NAME libcurl)`
Maybe the `LIB_NAME` variable is `libcurl`? I found that in the directory `\httpd\srclib\curl\bin\lib` there are several files related to `libcurl`: https://imgur.com/BXvU8Ku

Comment: Now, I need to add this line: `target_link_libraries(curl \httpd\srclib\curl\bin\lib)`
to `\httpd\CMakeLists.txt` right?

Comment: No, you add only `libcurl` (to existing call), the command should look something like `target_link_libraries(httpd libcurl)` but assuming `httpd` is an executable find `httpd` target's name (first arg to`add_executable` call).

Comment: `httpd` is the name of the root directory (containing the Apache source code), the directory containing the source code for the features is located in `httpd\srclib`, the global output directory `\phpStudy\Apache`. Did I add this correctly? https://imgur.com/wcpxtbo

Comment: The `target_link_libraries` call should be after target is created, find where `md_curl.c` name is written (I mean. added to be compiled), if was written in a `set`-method find where the resulting variable is used (should be used in an `add_executable` or `add_library` call).

Comment: I found `md_curl.c` in `CMakeLists.txt` and added below: https://imgur.com/i868tKH
Did I add correctly?

Comment: No, find where `mod_md_extra_sources` is used (the variable name is always the first argument of `set`-method), I said that actually in advance (to save your time).

Comment: None of the files use `mod_md_extra_sources`. I searched all the files contained in the `httpd` folder (including other feature's source code files). What should I do next?

Comment: Search the file you found `md_curl.c ` in for any `add_executable` or `add_library` calls (let's hope they did not move it out).

Comment: `md_curl.c` is no longer reused anywhere in `CMakeLists.txt`. I searched the entire file (as above) and only found `md_curl.c` contained in `mod_md.dsp` and `mod_md.mak`: https://imgur.com/a/2H4TSyr

Comment: Sorry, meant in the [file you sent image of](https://imgur.com/i868tKH) try to find any `add_executable` or `add_library` calls (don't search for `md_curl.c` again, meant in same file where it was found).

Comment: I uploaded the HTTPD `CMakeLists.txt` file here: https://github.com/tumatanquang/HTTPD/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt
I see that inside there are a lot of `add_executable` and `add_library` you said.

Comment: Try changing the `mod_md_extra_libs ` to `SET(mod_md_extra_libs    ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${JANSSON_LIBRARIES} mod_watchdog libcurl)` and rebuild (but I wonder what `CURL_LIBRARIES` variable contains).

Comment: The `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${mod_name}` is where that will be used, anyway, I will be offline soon, but if you still have the same issue; try adding `libcurl` to end of each of `target_link_libraries` calls (I mean those in the file you posted only).

Comment: Thank you, it compiled successfully after I edited it again as you said! Changing the `mod_md_extra_libs`  to `SET(mod_md_extra_libs    ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${JANSSON_LIBRARIES} mod_watchdog libcurl)`.

Comment: After editing to `SET(mod_md_extra_libs    ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${JANSSON_LIBRARIES} mod_watchdog libcurl)` do I still need to keep `add_subdirectory(srclib/curl)` in HTTPD `CMakeLists.txt`? Because I found that every time I compile HTTPD, it recompiles cURL one or two more times.

Comment: It is because `add_subdirectory` that CMake can automatically find `curl` just by using it's target-name (instead of directory). But you are right, it also causes a compile (but not more than once normally), **Either think about it as an advantage,** you no longer need to compile `cURL` yourself (and can remove it from "whole compile statement" thing). **Or use another approach, like**, after undoing current changes, find curl `.lib` file's directory, use `CMake-GUI` to open `httpd`'s root `CMakeFiles.txt` file, then you should be able to set the cURL's directory manually (without code).

Comment: I haven't removed `add_subdirectory(srclib/curl)` from `CMakeLists.txt` because I'm concerned it will cause HTTPD compilation errors (I don't know if it will cause compilation errors?). However, the cURL compile statement has changed slightly, I compile cURL 2 times: First time with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` flag, second time with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` flag before compiling HTTPD. So i think, the cURL compilation while the other HTTPD compile will use the flag `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` right?

Comment: Yes, the `add_subdirectory(...)` call basically just asks CMake to compile another `CMakeFile.txt` file with the same options as the current one, so, add `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` in your `** Apache Build **` section (if you need it).

Comment: Okay, I decided to keep that line. Hopefully their next update will fix the cURL related issue.
Thank you very much!